# How to delete my app from iTunes connect?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

My app is on Prepare for Submission, and I want to delete this app.
Already removed all countries from Territory Availibity.
But I cannot see the Delete Button.
What should I do?

Comment: Contact Apple directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. At least one version of the app needs to be online at least once
2. App must be offline
3. Only Agent role can see the Delete option